# Installation of RCommander (rcmdr)

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install RCommander so that I am able to play with .rdata files.

I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

As stated here:
http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

I cannot seem to access the `rcmdr` command!

Answer (score 4):

From RCommander installation [notes](https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/installation-notes.html) :

Linux/Unix systems typically have all of the software required for building packages already installed. The easiest way to install the Rcmdr package is to run R as root and issue the command install.packages("Rcmdr") at the R prompt.  R will ask you to select a CRAN mirror; pick the first, "0-Cloud" mirror, or a mirror site near you.

On Ubutu systems, in particular, the following procedure should work (slightly modified from a suggestion by Ista Zahn):

- to Ubuntu (see http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/)

  for ubuntu bionic

  ```
  echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Install base R and the R dev package:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
  ```
- Start R from the Ubuntu command line as root so you can install packages system-wide:

  ```
  sudo R
  ```
- From the R command prompt, install Rcmdr:

  ```
  install.packages("Rcmdr")
  ```

  - R will ask you to select a CRAN mirror
  - pick the first, "0-Cloud" mirror, or a mirror site near you.

It is also possible to install R and R packages from the Ubuntu package respository but these are almost always out of date.

When you first load the Rcmdr package with the command library(Rcmdr), it will offer to download and install missing dependencies; allow it to do so.

Comment: I do so but I get: installation of package ‘/home/mirza/Desktop/R/Rcmdr_2.5-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 0):

ensure that you have the R interpreter installed. open the R interpreter (from the command line: `R`) and run `install.package("Rcmdr")` in the interpreter.
Once this finishes, then run `library(Rcmdr)`. Allow it to install missing/updated dependencies.
You can then create a launcher for Rcmdr by running the following:

```
sudo cat >/usr/bin/Rcmdr <<EOF
#! /usr/bin/env bash
R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES="$R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES Rcmdr" R "$@"
EOF
chmod a+x /usr/bin/Rcmdr
```

now you can run Rcmdr from the command line by typing `Rcmdr`.